# How can a DPPH assay to measure antioxidant activity of beta carotene be conducted?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, food-chemistry

I am currently doing some research regarding beta-carotene. With reference to other sources and their methodoloy for DPPH assay, I conducted my experiment but failed to find any significant peak in absorbance at 517nm using a UV-spectro.

My sample of DPPH is already dissolved to 0.1mM in methanol.

My methodology was mixing-
0.3cm3 DPPH
0.3cm3 beta-carotene (dissolved in propanone)
2.4cm3 methanol

I increased the dissolved betacarotene in increments of 0.3cm3 ( upto 1.5cm3) while simultaneously decreasing methanol also by 0.3cm3 (upto 1.2 cm3) for a total of 5 readings.

The mixture was shaken and left to sit (in dark conditions) for 30mins before readings were taken using UV-spectrometer. The UV-spectrometer was calibrated with DPPH.

While I achieved the expected colour change from purple to yellow, I did not get a significant absorbance at any reading at 517nm even when using pure beta carotene.

I suspect this may be due to the betacarotene being dissolved in propanone which perhaps may be the wrong solvent, or perhaps i am calibrating the UV-spectro with the wrong substance, however I would like to check if this procedure is incorrect.

Please advice accordingly. Much appreciated.

Comment: After taking a glance at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPPH it seems like you would expect a purple DPPH solution that decolorizes when you add antioxidants or radical scavengers. Maybe try reacting with vitamin C as a positive control.

Comment: @Karsten Theis: I think it is actually yellowish at the end (decolorizing is acceptable). :-)

Comment: What do you mean by you calibrated UV-spectrometer by DPPH? Is it your control or blank? Also, absorbance of $\beta$-carotene may be interfering too.

Comment: I used it as blank.

Comment: I used to run this assay and I think 30 min is a lot longer than I let it sit for. Maybe try 5 minutes? Or else leave in the spectrometer and measure the change in the spectrum over time?